# Easiest way to recursively sort a vector?

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

This will sort vectors inside a vector:

```
std::vector<
    std::vector<int>
> my_vector {
    { 1, 3, 2 },
    { 52, 10, 20 },
    { 30, 2, 3 }
};
std::for_each(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), [] (std::vector<int>& v)
    {
        std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    });
```

It doesn't actually sort the elements of the outermost vector, so it isn't a "recursive" sort. A recursive sort would sort all of the vectors, including the outermost vector. For example, [prettyprint.hpp](https://louisdx.github.io/cxx-prettyprint/) will print containers recursively. I don't need to go over all the elements of every container, like prettyprinter does, only the ranges.

This is my try so far:

```
template <typename T>
void my_sort(std::vector<T>& v)
{
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), 
        [] (T& vv)
        {
            my_sort(vv);
        });
}
```

This doesn't work because when `T = int` it tries to call `my_sort` with int. Any tips?

The output should look like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 30], [10, 20, 52]]
^--- outermost vector
 ^---- inner vector
```

Comment: Have you tried template specialization?

Comment: "It doesn't actually sort the elements of the outermost vector" - the outermost-vector elements *are vectors*. Post *exactly* what you are hoping a resulting outmost vector would look like given your original source, and do so *in the question*; not in a comment.

Comment: Can you take away the downvote now? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the constraints you added [actually at about the same time I posted my answer]: how do you want to get the inner vectors sorted? Also, you clearly show the outer vector being sorted...

Comment: I didn't see that we posted it at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you should recurse first and only then sort the outer range. Otherwise you'll get somewhat random results as the inner containers are not in any canonical order. To make matters worse, the later sort will change the order of elements causing the outer vectors to be apparently out of order. Seems you want to have a conditional version of `my_sort()` dependent on whether the type `T` defines an associated `iterator` type. Since you use only `std::vector<T>`s an easier approach is to simply rely on partial ordering of templates, though:

```
template <typename T>
void my_sort(T const&) {
    // this function delibarately does nothing
}
template <typename T>
void my_sort(std::vector<T>& v) {
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](T& value) { my_sort(value); });
    std:sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

BTW, since this function actually never calls itself, neither directly nor indirectly, it is actually not really a recursive function: each instantiation of the function template is a different function.